# TcpListener constant error Only one usage of each address

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

I am trying to use a TcpListener. Every time I try to start the listener I get the error that the Address is already in use. I have looked at netstat and cant see anything on that endpoint(IP Address, Port).

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ip, 58000);
        listener.Start();
    }
}
```

When I run that I the error every time.

[image]

Comment: almost certainly you still have old copies of yr program running. Or somebody else listening on the port. use sysinternals tcpview to find out. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

Comment: Looks like the port is being used by another process. Try executing netstat -nt command and check if port 58000 is being used by any other process

Comment: tcpview solved the problem. great thx

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear that another process (it's probably because of unfinisted exe of your program) bind the same port which you want to listen. Try to listen different port and see the case;

```
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ip, 58001);
listener.Start();
```

Also, I strongly suggest you to use [TcpView](http://IPAddress%20ip%20=%20IPAddress.Parse(%22127.0.0.1%22);%20TcpListener%20listener%20=%20new%20TcpListener(ip,%2058000);%20listener.Start();) to inspect allocated ports.

Answer (score 1):

You have for sure another process(most probably the same you are trying to run) running in background so you cannot open the port. Try to open and and ensure to close the connections:

```
public static void Main()
  { 
    TcpListener server=null;   
    try
    {
      Int32 port = 58000;
      IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

      // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
      server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

      // Start listening for client requests.
      server.Start();

      // DO ALL YOUR WORK
    }
    catch(SocketException e)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
       // Stop listening for new clients.
       server.Stop();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I will add the try catch block and finally block to my logic